# Error "The resource cannot be found" while submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to submit a simple form in ASP and am having issues getting it to recognize my route. I come from a php background so this is all new to me.

1. How do I register my route Correctly?
2. How do I get my form values in my controller?

My Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product" , FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer:</label>
        <select name="cus_no" class="form-control">
            <option value="2000">Target</option>
            <option value="4000">Wal-Mart</option>
            <option value="4200">Amazon</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Item:</label>
        <select name="item_no" class="form-control">
            <option value="6000">SkyWinder</option>
            <option value="60001">Somerset</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Unit Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="unit_price" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="start_date" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer Warehouse Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cus_warehouse_cd" class="form-control" placeholder="optional"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
}
```

My Controller which is doing nothing right now.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // POST: Product/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And my RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Product",
            url: "Product/Create/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Create", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? When you submit the form? Or when you try to load the page that the form is on?

Comment: @mason When I submit the form

Comment: We generally don't use `FormCollection` in MVC. You can define a strongly typed object (just a class with properties) that matches the structure of the data you're submitting. The framework's model binder will then create an instance of that object based on the submitted values and pass that to your controller's action method. Have you looked at [the documentation](https://www.asp.net/mvc)?

Comment: As mason mentioned, be mindful of MVCs 'convention over configuration'.  It caught me out when I started.  If the field names you pass in the post  matchup to the strongly typed object set in your controllers ActionResult signature it should get populated automatically.

Comment: I'll take a look at the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: IMO: catching an exception and eating the valuable error message is a _huge_ waste of both your time and of the readers of your question.

Comment: The code you have shown will not give that exception. And your 2nd route (`Product`) is pointless since `/Product/Create` also matches the 1st route (routes are matched in order)

Comment: You need to show the exact details of the error your getting.

Comment: comment out the second route definition and change the form collection to Product Object.